# Manipulations with complex numbers, phasors

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry, algebra

I am trying to implement phasor arithmetic, but cannot get it to work well. The key is that the arguments to the phasor function are Reals, but I cannot get Mathematica to deal with that efficiently.

For example:

```
f[t_] := Cos[w*t] + i*Sin[w*t]
```

is what I want, with `w` and `t` real. I'd like to see this happen:
`Re[f[t]] = Cos[w*t]` etc. I would think this would work, but it does not:

```
f[t_] := Cos[Re[w]*Re[t]]+i*Sin[Re[w]*Re[t]]
```

This yields:

`Re[f[t]]` is `-Im[Sin[Re[t] Re[w]]] + Re[Cos[Re[t] Re[w]]]`. Annoying.

`Refine[Re[f[t]]]` is `Cos[Re[t] Re[w]]` which is better.

`FullSimplify[Arg[f[t]]]` is `Arg[E^(I Re[t] Re[w])]` which is silly (`I` is sqrt(-1)).

`FullSimplify[Abs[f[t]]]` is 1, which is correct!

If I do this:

```
arg[thing_] := ArcTan[Im[thing]/Re[thing]]
```

For:

```
arg[f[t]]
```

I get:

```
ArcTan[(Im[Cos[Re[t] Re[w]]] + 
Re[Sin[Re[t] Re[w]]])/(-Im[Sin[Re[t] Re[w]]] + Re[Cos[Re[t] Re[w]]])]
```

Clearly `Im[Cos[Re[t] Re[w]]]` is zero. How do I achieve that? `FullSimplify` gets to this point:

```
FullSimplify[arg[f[t]]]
```

I am left with:

```
ArcTan[Tan[Re[t] Re[w]]]
```

which is annoying but perhaps correct? `ArcTan` is not strictly the inverse of `Tan`?

Comment: Do you add assumptions to `FullSimplify`?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I did not see the need, since I added `Re[]` and `Im[]` in the function, which return real values unambiguously. Also, I had previously used the `$Assumptions` variable, so I did not need to add assumptions in the FullSimplify call. (I even tried that but it did not have an effect).

Comment: Do you know whether for `f[t,w]=Re[t]Re[w]`  $-\frac{\pi}{2}<f\left( t,w\right) <\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: I rather mean that you may include very wide range of assumptions (using things like patterns, etc.) - unfortunately I do not master these well enough to figure out what can be done

Comment: Note that a phasor is a _constant_ complex quantity, it does not vary with time. For an example see e.g. [this answer of mine on EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/231659/87069).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thanks for the correct usage of the term.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე That is a hint: how to get Tan[ArcTan[x] to simplify to x. Assumptions may be involved. Thank you.

Comment: @AnthonyMannucci With this specific case, Mathematica answers to `Tan[ArcTan[x]]` with `x`, without any assumptions (mine is 11.0.1)

Comment: If you mean `ArcTan[Tan[x]]`, I get `x` from `Simplify[ArcTan[Tan[x]], Assumptions -> -\[Pi]/2 < x < \[Pi]/2]`

Comment: My original expectation is incorrect. `Re[f[t]]` is not `Cos[w*t]` if t and w are not real. It now seems to work correctly with `Assumptions -> {Element[w,Reals], Element[t,Reals]}`, so I don't know what I was doing wrong. I.e. `Refine[Re[f[t]], 
 Assumptions -> {Element[w, Reals], Element[t, Reals]}]` yields `Cos[tw]`